# Edge 44 renders mat-table sticky header incorrectly

Tags: html, scroll, angular-material, microsoft-edge, mat-table

Recently our users upgraded to the latest version of Microsoft Edge:

Old version:

- Microsoft Edge 41.16299.1419.0
- Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

New version:

- Microsoft Edge 44.17763.771.0
- Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763

We are using mat-table sticky header and see that with the new browser, the header (and sticky footer if present) if incorrectly offset too high.

You can even see this problem on the official document page:
https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview

Scroll down to "Table with sticky header"

Bad rendering:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4pTE.jpg

Good rendering:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmUna.jpg

Has anyone seen an open edge issue on this, or have a work around?

Comment: I've tested in Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0 and reproduced the issue. I also found a similar [issue report](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11921) in github. Thank you for letting us know about this issue in MS Edge. I will try to submit this feedback to website for Edge issues. For now, you could check this [angular example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sticky-column-header) as a work around, it can work well in Edge.

Comment: @YuZhou, thanks - I did find that removing the mat-elevation-z8 from the parent div fixed the issue.  Looks like maybe its related to box shadows or padding from parent divs being included in offset.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to your question otherwise we can't provide anything more than guesses.

Comment: @TylerH here is the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/pknye9vt/1/
it doesnt show as bad as the example on angulars web page, but you can see in edge the header row text is a bit too high.

Comment: @sdparker Please add that code to the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with senior engineers, we think it should be a issue of Angular Material. Angular Material should change their design to adapt Microsoft Edge(EdgeHTML). We could wait for the next update of Angular Material to see if it will solve the issue.

For now, we can use [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sticky-column-header) as a workaround or the solution you mentioned in the comment that removing the `mat-elevation-z8` from the parent div.